# cakephp 4 seems not to initiate session

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to migrate an app from cake 3.9 to 4.1. I have some code in AppController::beforeRender which checks for a session var which I write from a login page.

So in the login page I do a

```
$this->request->getSession()->write($this->_adminCookie, true);
```

and in my AppController I have

```
$sessionCookie = $this->request->getSession()->read($this->_adminCookie);
```

but it always return null. DebugKit shows also session is null and if I dump $this->request->getSession() I get

```
object(Cake\Http\Session)[25]
  protected '_engine' => null
  protected '_started' => null
  protected '_lifetime' => int 1440
  protected '_isCLI' => boolean false
```

I have in app.local Session default to cake and run the page with bin/cake server. Any help what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you try to read the session right after writing it, does it work?

Comment: yes it works and print correctly

Comment: Then I would look to see if it's getting deleted somewhere else. Or maybe the value of `$this->_adminCookie` is different for the two calls?